# How to add pdf File in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

/C:/Users/abuze/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-21.2.6/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:2074:58: Error: Member not found: 'EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding'.
double keyPadHeight = EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/abuze/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-21.2.6/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:2070:27: Error: The getter 'View' isn't defined for the class 'SfPdfViewerState'.

- 'SfPdfViewerState' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/src/pdfviewer.dart' ('/C:/Users/abuze/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-21.2.6/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart').
  pdfviewer.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'View'.
  View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0.0;
  ^^^^

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

I want to add pdf file in flutter. what's solve?

Answer (score 0):

If by adding PDF to Flutter, you mean you would like your Flutter app to generate PDF files, you can use the PDF package.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf
```

If you want to just display PDF files, you can just use URL Launcher to launch the PDF file and let the user choose whichever PDF viewer they like.